# Add user desired color to textview. xcode

Tags: xcode, fonts, ios5, xcode4.2, uicolor

I have a UIPickerView, where in which I have an array of sentences.

Now how can I return an array of colors? such that on picking the color, I must assign it to the sentence.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Method - `(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;` will be called when you select a row.

Your data source will be having the title you had set.

Comment: Yeah I have 2 components, My question.. How do I pass an array of colors in the next component?

Comment: How are you passing data for component for the first? The same way to the second... Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, let me try it out. Thanks for the ans bro!1

Comment: Dont forget to rate if that had helped you :)